# How can I find all paths where the path does not include a specific number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a table that has a Path column and a Client column. I want to find the rows where the Client No can't be found anywhere in the Path.

Table Columns:

**Path**

> Z:_IMANAGE READ ONLY\47640-001 - 002 - Blue Buffalo Company\47640.001
>   -- Blue Buffalo\E-Mail Correspondence\Internal\2766005.1-RE- Invoices.MSG

`Client 47640`

`Matter 1`

What I have so far:

```
select Path, Client, Matter
from DocData
where Imported = 'Y'
  and Path Not Like '%' + (select top 1 cast(Client as nvarchar(10)) from DocData) + '%'
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: What is the point of the subquery?  Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Server. The point of the subquery was to compare the 2 columns. One needing to be found in the other. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a subquery, the following should work:

```
select Path, Client, Matter
from DocData
where Imported = 'Y'
  and Path Not Like '%' + cast(Client as nvarchar(10)) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I must be tired. I severely over-complicated that.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is working perfectly fine, you have a mistake in your `ncarchar` I think you mean `nvarchar` ( that would work fine )

I would not use your own query even though it *is not wrong*. It is not going to return the value you are needing.

**Instead use the shortened query without the subquery**

**Change the following**

```
select Path, Client, Matter
from DocData
where Imported = 'Y'
  and Path Not Like '%' + (select top 1 cast(Client as ncarchar(10)) from DocData) + '%'
```

**To ( if you want to fix the error )**

```
select Path, Client, Matter
from DocData
where Imported = 'Y'
  and Path Not Like '%' + (select top 1 cast(Client as nvarchar(10)) from DocData) + '%'
```

**Correct query without the subquery**

*(With (your own query) the top 1 subquery you never know which row you are comparing to)*

```
select Path, Client, Matter
from DocData
where Imported = 'Y'
  and Path Not Like '%' + cast(Client as nvarchar(10)) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks . In addition to the typo, someone also pointed out that I didn't need the subquery.

Comment: "The subquery has no real extra value" not only does it not add value, it's plainly wrong. With the `top 1` subquery you never know which row you are comparing to.

Comment: shouldnt use a subquery as its most likely to not return the same row as what you are comparing to

Comment: @HoneyBadger that is actually a very good comment il add that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `CHARINDEX()` function.

```
CREATE TABLE TestPath
(
[Path] Nvarchar(100),
[Id] int,
Matter bit
)

Insert INTO TestPath
Values
('C:\Test\SQL_Query\47641_001_Blue_Red',47641,1),
('C:\Test\SQL_Query\47642_001_Blue_Red',47642,1),
('C:\Test\SQL_Query\47643_001_Blue_Red',47643,1),
('C:\Test\SQL_Query\47646_001_Blue_Red',47644,1),
('C:\Test\SQL_Query\47649_001_Blue_Red',47645,1)

select [Path], id, Matter
from TestPath
where CHARINDEX(Cast(Id as Varchar(10)),[Path])<>0
```

This will get you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. This worked too.

Select Path, Client, Matter
From DocData
Where Charindex(Cast(Client as NVarchar(10)),Path,0) = 0
 And Imported = 'Y'